# how to install pygobject for python3 in fedora18

Tags: fedora, gtk3, pygobject, python-3.3

i try to install pygobject for python 3 in fedora 18 
i read this doc https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html and i try to install jhbuild after that when i type $ jhbuild sanitycheck
get this error : bash: jhbuild: command not found...

i try to install with yum , i install "pygobject3-devel" but this not work with python3 
in fedora 18 default python is python2.7.3, i install python3.3.0 with yum and test a first demo code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

after give chmod +x for this python file can run with this command "./test.py" 
and if i try to run with python (with out use #! ....) and type this command "$python test.py" that run and work without any problem but when i type this command "$python3 test.py" i get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk
ImportError: No module named 'gi'
```

have any idea ?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing `pygobject3` instead of `pygobject3-dev` (as a matter of fact, it seems that pygobject3 is already installed in a vainilla installation of Fedora).

After installing that package, you should be able to open your interpreter (python2.7) and do:

`from gi.repository import Gtk`

<strike>If you want to use python3 (I didn't understand if you meant that you *tried* to use python3 or you *want* to use python3), it seems that the gnome instrospection bindings are not yet available, according to [this page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Python3) that summarizes the state of different packages python3-related that are being on the works.</strike>

**EDIT:** I just tried installing `python3-gobject` (which should be installed when installing `pygobject3`, but it doesn't for some reason) and it seems to be working aswell on python3.

Comment: thank you so much , after install python3-gobject that problem is solved , thanks now working very well with python3 :)

Comment: yum install python3-gobject worked a charm. I already had pygobject3 installed, but that installed it for 2.7 not 3.3.